# SQL Server 05, which is optimal, LIKE %<term>% or CONTAINS() for searching large column

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, query-optimization

I've got a function written by another developer which I am trying to modify for a slightly different use.  It is used by a SP to check if a certain phrase exists in a text document stored in the DB, and returns 1 if the value is found or 0 if its not.  This is the query:

```
SELECT @mres=1 from documents where id=@DocumentID
 and contains(text, @search_term)
```

The document contains mostly XML, and the search_term is a GUID formatted as an nvarchar(40).

This seems to run quite slowly to me (taking 5-6 seconds to execute this part of the process), but in the same script file there is also this version of the above, commented out.

```
SELECT @mres=1 from documents where id=@DocumentID
and textlike '%' + @search_term + '%'
```

This version runs MUCH quicker, taking 4ms compared to 15ms for the first example.

So, my question is why use the first over the second?  I assume this developer (who is no longer working with me) had a good reason, but at the moment I am struggling to find it..

Is it possibly something to do with the full text indexing? (this is a dev DB I am working with, so the production version may have better indexing..)  I am not that clued up on FTI really so not quite sure at the moment.  Thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Aggg - all of my answer is wrong!

Yes, `CONTAINS` is indeed using full-text search (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and so should be quick (or at least it should properly scale)

The reason why the second version (using `LIKE`) could be quicker is if your table doesn't contain many rows - invoking the full text engine for searches will incur a small additional overhead which might mean that using `LIKE` is marginally quicker for small tables.

On the other hand if the top query is taking 5-6 seconds to execute then I'd say that something is probably wrong somewhere - again try looking at the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be case where one option would be faster than the other, and vice-versa.  Your best option would be to test the same query on production, and see the difference.  For this kind of performance testing, I would recommend using profiler, and running each query multiple times, and taking an average to compare