# What is the most effective way to test if a string contains another one in MSSQL?

Tags: php, performance, svn, sql-server-2000, pre-commit-hook

I need to test if a string (filenames with their complete path) contains another one in MSSQL.

My script needs to check if the file we are about to commit is present in the database under a specific column (pre-hook script).

I cannot really change the data definition of the column, but we are currently using text `TEXT` and files are seperated by a new line character. I tried to use TSQL function `CONTAINS`, but the overall performance is not really good.

Would it be a better idea to load all the data in a PHP array and do the comparaison locally ?

I'm not quite sure what is best way to do here.

**Update:** There is about 194 530 rows in the database.

Comment: What version of MSSQL?  2008, 2005, 2000, 7

Comment: The application is running under MSSQL 2000 (I know, this is old). I know that we have a 2005 box as well here, probably we can move the database to that server, but I'm not sure about this. Right now, I think I will have to deal with MSSQL 2000 :(

Comment: Some of this is a little unclear: you're storing multiple filenames in a single row-column pair, correct?

Comment: Yes. I have a column "files", so for a specific ID, I have a list of files seperated by a new line character in the database. Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453338/sql-server-05-which-is-optimal-like-term-or-contains-for-searching-large

Comment: Yeah, that's going to be really bad to handle in SQL just because of the poor normalization. Your intended goal is to see whether a specific path+file combination already exists?

Comment: Well, I meant a list of files with their complete path, like the following: `D:\wwwroot\folder\folder1\iamnotafile.txt` And yes, I agree this is poorly normalized. I need to work on this project at my internship. Things are pretty bad here actually...

Comment: Do all the files listed in a row have the same path?

Comment: Side question - what you want to solve in pre-commit hook? I can't imagine **business task**. And "one row in table - one commit", is it true?

Comment: tl;dr: they are using a bug tracking system which stores information plus files involved in bugs. They want to _block_ commits if a file is involved in a bug with a _special_ status... We have a bug table with all the information associated with bugs, as well as a column used for storing files involved in them. I know this is badly normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to keep in mind when doing a search through a string is that you want to limit the length of the string you are searching through. Right now, you have multiple path+filename values tucked into a single row-column pair - as I've mentioned above, this is poorly normalized (and is part of the reason you're having trouble doing lookups).

Given that you can't really change the schema of the table you're having trouble with, a better alternative might be creating a structure to work with the metadata that describes the files stored within a certain row.

For example, one option might be to create a table that contains `filename`-`rowID` pairs, where each row of the original table is linked to the parsed-out filenames within the `TEXT`column of that row. That gives you the option of limiting your search by first doing a lookup on a shorter string (the `filename`), and then using that constraint to help search a smaller number of rows to satisfy the path+filename combination and achieve a unique result.

If you have a large number of files with identical names, another option might be to implement a hash index, using `rowID`s from your original table and a hash of each path+filename from that row using `CHECKSUM()` or whatever hashing function you have available.

Using an 'indexing' table like this one does add overhead: you have to maintain the metadata as the original table gets updated, but it also means you're doing your heavy lifting ahead of time and making future queries of the data much faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `LIKE` operator? You could do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%' + @FilePath +'%'
```

If this does not fit your needs, then, I would agree that doing this programmatically might be better. The problem is that SQL uses set based logic, so when you begin doing something that is more procedural (functions), it breaks down. Obviously, run tests, but programmatically you should be able to do this quicker. You could use regular expressions or contains or whatever might be best within php

Comment: This is the first thing I have tried, I personally found that performances were better with CONTAINS (Maybe it's just me...). Also, I don't think we have an index on this column neither....

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois Then, I would agree that doing this programmatically might be better. The problem is that SQL uses set based logic, so when you begin doing something that is more procedural (functions), it breaks down. Obviously, run tests, but programmatically you should be able to do this quicker. You could use regular expressions or contains or whatever might be best within php.

Comment: That is what I tought too. But now the question is, what would be the correct way to store all these rows in PHP ? Storing this in an array would end up in filling up the RAM, am I wrong ?

Comment: My expertise is not in PHP, so I dont know what its strong suits are. If there is a way that you could page through the data and/or yield it, that might be best.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be faster:

```
SELECT TOP 1 columnname FROM tablename WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%' + @FilePath +'%'
```

Comment: +1 for the edit, but I don't think it'll be any faster in practice.